# PHP Composer - Update from a remote server?

Tags: remote-access, composer-php

I have been looking at using Composer for a project of mine, and I'm wondering, is it possible to update a copy of a project "checked out" from composer?

case and point, I get the project off of composer, I then upload it to the web server (if its possible to avoid that step, a major bonus). an update is found, would I be able to just run the update from the remote source?

If more explanation is needed, please let me know as composer looks very promising to me.

Comment: I think you need to rewrite your question. As it's written it makes almost no sense, and so is impossible to answer.

Comment: the question was if I'm able to update my code I got from composer, simply I found my own answer. you just need to access the site from SSH and run the update command, that did it for me. Composer is still new to me so excuse my improper question towards it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have just played around with things a bit before asking, for those who may want to know themselves. if you got composer installed on the server, you can access it remotely by SSH.